# Transition upper div after slide animation

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I have a problem with css transitions. How can I set transition animation upper div after remove lower with slide animation? My current code works like this upper div just falls quickly but I would like to make it "slow slide". There is a way to do it with pure css? I don't want use any plugins.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var obj = $('#o2');

  obj.click(function() {

    obj.addClass('removed');
    obj.one('animationend', function() {
      obj.remove();
    });

  });

});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.obj {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  animation: slide-in 1s forwards;
}

.removed {
  animation: slide-out 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes slide-out {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="obj" id="o1">obj1</div>
  <div class="obj" id="o2">obj2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an animation to the `o1` and move it to bottom before removing the `o2`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var obj = $('#o2');

  obj.click(function() {

    obj.addClass('removed');
    obj.on('animationend', function() {
      $('#o1').addClass('slide-down').on('animationend', function() {
        obj.remove();
      });
    });

  });

});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.obj {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0%);
  animation: slide-in 1s ;
}

.removed {
  animation: slide-out 1s forwards;
}

.slide-down {
  animation: slide-down 1s linear;
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes slide-down {
  100% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes slide-out {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="obj" id="o1">obj1</div>
  <div class="obj" id="o2">obj2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for help but I want slide in from actual position to lower position (from up to down).

Comment: Thanks for help! Unfortunately, this solution creates another problem because I have to give the size (200px) in animation and in the original code the divs are of random height (I wouldnt like to use tons of jQuery code to check previous div' height because it will make another problem for example with scaling page :( ).

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much!